# C# Form.Close vs Form.Dispose

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C#, and I tried to look at the earlier posts but did not find a good answer.

In a C# Windows Form Application with a single form, is using `Form.Close()` better or `Form.Dispose()`?

MSDN says that all resources within the object are closed and the form is disposed when a Close is invoked. Inspite of which, I have come across several examples online which follow a Dispose rather than a Close.

Does one have an advantage over the other? Under which scenarios should we prefer one over the other?

Comment: Slightly different question, same answer, IMO: i.e. Close and Dispose are usually equivalent, except that you can call Close more than once.

Comment: @Chrisw: You can also call Dispose more than once.

Comment: @ChrisW, Dispose should be designed to run more than once as well. http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=88e62cdf-5919-4ac7-bc33-20c06ae539ae

Comment: The thing that got me that close === dispose rather than close == form.Visible = false ; I was expecting that close would be a softer method than dispose.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham: If you want `form.Visible = false;` you can call `form.Hide()`. In fact, `form.Hide()` simply sets `this.Visible = false;`.

Comment: [Do I need to Dispose a Form after the Form got Closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834)

Answer (score 194, accepted):

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5cbf16a9-1721-4861-b7c0-ea20cf328d48) forum on MSDN tells you.

> `Form.Close()` sends the proper Windows
>   messages to shut down the win32
>   window. During that process, if the
>   form was not shown modally, Dispose is
>   called on the form. Disposing the form
>   frees up the unmanaged resources that
>   the form is holding onto.
>
> If you do a `form1.Show()` or
>   `Application.Run(new Form1())`, Dispose
>   will be called when `Close()` is called.
>
> However, if you do `form1.ShowDialog()`
>   to show the form modally, the form
>   will not be disposed, and you'll need
>   to call `form1.Dispose()` yourself.  I
>   believe this is the only time you
>   should worry about disposing the form
>   yourself.

Comment: Did the 1st version include the quote?  +1 to compensate.

Comment: @Dan the first version sucked... (Sorry @Kyra)

Comment: This is somewhat not the same as MSDN states at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28VS.80%29.aspx: "The one condition when a form is not disposed on Close is when it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible. In this case, you will need to call Dispose  manually to mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection." However, it should be easy to check whether modal forms are disposed or not with a simple sample.

Comment: [Do I need to Dispose a Form after closing the Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Might want to fix the link though :)

Answer (score 16):

As a general rule, I'd always advocate explicitly calling the Dispose method for any class that offers it, either by calling the method directly or wrapping in a "using" block.

Most often, classes that implement IDisposible do so because they wrap some unmanaged resource that needs to be freed.  While these classes should have finalizers that act as a safeguard, calling Dispose will help free that memory earlier and with lower overhead.

In the case of the Form object, as the link fro Kyra noted, the Close method is documented to invoke Dispose on your behalf so you need not do so explicitly.  However, to me, that has always felt like relying on an implementaion detail.  I prefer to always call both Close and Dispose for classes that implement them, to guard against implementation changes/errors and for the sake of being clear.  A properly implemented Dispose method should be safe to invoke multiple times.

Comment: [Do I need to Dispose a Form after closing the Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39501121/3110834)

Answer (score 8):

Not calling `Close` probably bypasses sending a bunch of Win32 messages which one would think are somewhat important though I couldn't specifically tell you why...

`Close` has the benefit of raising events (that can be cancelled) such that an outsider (to the form) could watch for `FormClosing` and `FormClosed` in order to react accordingly.

I'm not clear whether `FormClosing` and/or `FormClosed` are raised if you simply dispose the form but I'll leave that to you to experiment with.

Comment: If you dispose the form, then closing and closed events are not called.

Comment: calling Dispose method would cause flickering of the window when used on Modal-Form over mdi-child window

Answer (score 4):

<sub>An old question, having some good answers, but I want to share a clear answer for this very popular question</sub>

---

### How do I close Form in code?

- **Did you open the form using `Show`?**

  Then to close it in code, just call `Close()`.
- **Did you open the form using `ShowDialog`?**

  Then close it by `Close` or by setting `DialogResult`.

### Do I need to dispose Form?

- **Did you open the form using `Show`?**

  No you don't need. After you close the form by `Close` or by clicking on X, it will be disposed automatically.
- **Did you open the form using `ShowDialog`?**

  Yes you need. After you close the form by `Close` or by setting `DialogResult` or by clicking on X, if you are not going to reuse the form, you need to explicitly call `Dispose`, or make sure you create the form instance in a `using` block like this:

  ```
  //form will be disposed after the using block
  using (var f = new MyForm())
  {
      if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
          //Your logic to handle OK here
      }
  }
  ```

  If you want to reuse it later, then do not forget to explicitly `Dispose` in when you no more need it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `using`is a pretty good way:

```
using (MyForm foo = new MyForm())
{
    if (foo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Close() - managed resource can be temporarily closed and can be opened once again.

Dispose() - permanently removes managed or not managed resource

Comment: This is true only if the form was shown using `ShowDialog()`. Otherwise,`Close()` will dispose the form as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you use form.close() in your form and set the FormClosing Event of your form and either use  form.close() in this Event ,you fall in unlimited loop and Argument out of range happened and the solution is that change the form.close() with form.dispose() in Event of FormClosing.
I hope this little tip help you!!!

Answer (score -1):

What I have just experiment with VS diagnostic tools is I called this.Close() then formclosing event triggered. Then When I call this.Dispose() at the end in Formclosing event where I dispose many other objects in it, it cleans everything much much smoother.