# Correct calling of Dispose() for opened form

Tags: .net, winforms

Let's suppose I have 2 forms: `FormA` and `FormB`. On `FormA` button click the instance of `FormB` is created and shown.

How to `Dispose()` `FormB` instance correctly after it has been closed?

To be more precise, let's suppose this is the code that creates a form:

```
    public void Settings(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_settings == null)
            _settings = new Settings(_repositoryCollection, _config, this);

        _settings.Show();
        _settings.Focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a modal dialog, use

```
using (var settings = new Settings(_repositoryCollection, _config, this))
{
   settings.ShowDialog ();
}
```

Otherwise, for a normal form shown at the same time as FormA... you may not even have to.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097364/c-form-close-vs-form-dispose).:

```
_settings = new Settings(_repositoryCollection, _config, this);
_settings.Closed += delegate {_settings.Dispose ();};
```

Comment: So just add it to `Closed` event? Is it ok to dispose an object from an event triggered by itself?

Comment: "During that process, if the form was not shown modally, Dispose is called on the form." --- but the more I call that method - the more memory is consumed by application :-S

Comment: If you want to be doubly sure that it's disposed, then yes.  But `When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed.`  That applies to windows that are shown with `.Show`.

Comment: Or even more strange - the memory consumption grows for the 7-9 window creatings after which it just stops growing more and stays the same value regardless new calls :-S So - seems like "everything is fine". Thanks. **UPD**: argh, nope - it grows the more I open that window :-S