# Loop through all MDI children and close all other forms except the current

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I am working on a winforms application using c#. I have an MDI container that has a menu on the left and by pushing a button then the appropriate form is visible. If I click for ex 3 times the button which opens Form1 the 6 instances of the form are opened. Thus I thought that I have to write a method that disposes any other Form1 instances. With the following method, I'm looping through the MDI children, but I want some help how to close all other instances except the new one.

```
  public void DisposeAllButThis(Form form)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (frm == form)
            {
                frm.Dispose();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check whether the form is of the same type too:

```
public void DisposeAllButThis(Form form)
{
    foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (frm.GetType() == form.GetType() 
            && frm != form)
        {
            frm.Dispose();
            frm.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on Close and Dispose see: [C# Form.Close vs Form.Dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097364/c-sharp-form-close-vs-form-dispose)

Comment: BTW: I just changed the code a bit by removing the premature return statement in the loop!

Comment: you are not disposing the form before closing it.

Comment: @Helper - I added the call to Dispose. BTW: if these forms are visible calling Close is sufficient

Comment: you should dispose first and then make it closed.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void DisposeAllButThis(Form form)
{
    foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (frm != form)
        {
            frm.Dispose();   
            frm.Close();          
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
{
   if (frm != form)
   {
      frm.Dispose();
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By this fanction You can call it from another class   : 
and note of this : `frm.GetType() != Parent.GetType()`

```
public void DisposeAllButThis(Form parentForm)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in Parent.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (frm.GetType() != Parent.GetType()
                && frm != Parent)
            {
                frm.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void closallforms()
        {
            foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                if (frm != Parent)
                {
                    frm.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you added some explanation and links to documentation, so the original poster and other users can actually learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

if you call from another child form you can use:             `this.DisposeAllButThis(this.FindForm());`

and use the method:

```
private void DisposeAllButThis(Form form)
{
    foreach (Form frm in ParentForm.MdiChildren)
    {
       if (frm != form)
       {
          frm.Dispose();
          frm.Close();
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ActiveMdiChild != null)
    ActiveMdiChild.Close();
```

Comment: Hi, you need give more information inv your anwser