# How to close the previous child form on clicking another child form in mdi using c#

Tags: c#, forms

I have a mdi parent form and I open my other forms in run time as mdi child form by this code:

```
private void winAppToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Upload objWA = new Upload();
            objWA.MdiParent = this;
            objWA.Show();
            //objWA.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void userInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Reports objUI = new Reports();
            objUI.MdiParent = this;
            objUI.Show();
            //objUI.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
```

but the problem is: When current form is open, user can open another form and it can be repeated several times so that each form is opened what's code for closing the previous child form before user open a new child form??

Screen shot for reference
[if we see the image my upload and reports forms both are getting opened on one another but it should only show the currently opened form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lgxsi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close all open forms except the main menu in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029351/close-all-open-forms-except-the-main-menu-in-c-sharp)

Comment: i had already tried this but its not working

Comment: Do u want to close previous instances of the _form_, when a new instance is created? If that is so, then any unsaved data in the previous one would get lost

Comment: yes i should close or hide previous form when new form is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void winAppToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Upload objWA = new Upload();
        objWA.MdiParent = this;
        objWA.Show();
        //objWA.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void userInfoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Reports objUI = new Reports();
        objUI.MdiParent = this;
        objUI.Show();
        DisposeAllButThis(Form objUI);
        //objUI.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
    public void DisposeAllButThis(Form form)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (frm.GetType() == form.GetType() 
                && frm != form)
            {
                frm.Dispose();
                frm.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

let me know if it worked because i just made it up

Comment: i am getting three errors near DisposeAllButThis(Form objUI);  Error1 ) expected                                                      
 Error 2 Invalid expression term ')'                                                              Error 3 ; expected

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DisposeAllButThis(Form form){
foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
{
    if (frm.GetType() == form.GetType() 
        && frm != form)
    {
        frm.Dispose();
        frm.Close();
    }
}}
```

got this from: 
[C# loop through all MDI childer and close all other forms except the current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308821/c-sharp-loop-through-all-mdi-childer-and-close-all-other-forms-except-the-curren)

Comment: could you please edit my post and can you show where should i include your code because i am completely new to this